# How to acces nested objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to access a specific field inside the nested array. My code is like this:

```
var array1 = [];

const data =  { [userId]: [{
             id: id,
             name: fullName,
             email: userEmail },
            ],
          };

array1.push(data);
```

If I print this:

```
console.log("index 0: ", array1[0]);
```

It gives this result:

```
index 0:  {
  buMqSZpEaKZABffDGNs5jzVK36Y2: [
    {
      id: '65',
      name: 'nameTest',
      email: 'myexmail@gmail.com'
    }
  ]
}
```

However, I would like to know how I can access the information inside the userId, like userId.name and be able to find a specific userId. For example, in the array1 find userId "aePoUZpkUnlAOMNBGNs5ynMD36L1" and display its information as if I did like this `activeSockets[0].` or `indexOf()`. Most of the times I have tried accessing the fields inside it says `Cannot read property '' of undefined`. Any help will appreciated

Comment: So, before we go down this road, quick question.  What is the purpose of the array?  Since your object has the key of the userid, and you can have multiple key value pairs in an object, what is your intended usage of the array?

Comment: So I can compare to check if the userid exists in the array, if exists only replace the id inside the userid

Comment: That can be done with a simple object.  `data[userId]` will return undefined or null if it does not exist.  And if it does exist, `data[userId].id = <newValue>` works too

Comment: I want to deal with array1[ ] because I push the data into it. The data[ ] will loose the old information.

Comment: So you're planning on having an array, that contains objects which consist of a single key to a sub-object value?

Comment: I did not get what you mean but, the structure is this:  
{
  buMqSZpEaKZABffDGNs5jzVK36Y2: [
    {
      id: '65',
      name: 'nameTest',
      email: 'myexmail@gmail.com'
    }
  ]
}

Comment: And your wanting to put that in an array.  So it's actually something like, `[ { buMqSZpEaKZABffDGNs5jzVK36Y2: [ { id: '65', name: 'nameTest', email: 'myexmail@gmail.com' } ] }, { buMqSZpEaKZABffDGNs5jzVK3333: [ { id: '78', name: 'nameTest2', email: 'blah@gmail.com' } ] } ]` ?

Comment: Yes. I am able to put in the array1. But I have problem accessing the data inside.

Comment: Right, so what my comments are saying is that outer most array is unnecessary, and is going to create problems that you have to solve.  So I'm suggesting instead of solving the problem, don't create it in the first place.

Comment: And how am I supposed to organize the information so that every user's fields are accessed through the userId?

Comment: Your `userId` are the keys of the single object.  [Your version](https://jsonblob.com/3d6fe6b9-4228-11ea-9498-fb21253edeb7).  [My proposal](https://jsonblob.com/60fd27d4-4228-11ea-9498-897ab40e8177)  My version will not require you to perform a filter/find on the object every time you need to access a user by their userid

Comment: That is how I did, if you check the description. My problem is to access a field, let's say the name or email inside.

Comment: That's not how you did it.  Your OP has the data being put in an `array1`, and then later you use `array1[0]` to access it.  If you have multiple users, you will have to perform a find to get it.  If you don't use an array, and use just the object, you don't have to do the find.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: For what data you have provided and the for the objective you described, your use (*misuse?*) of array and object data structures are over complicated. You should have only one object for each user then push them into one array. An array with only one user object is absurd especially if that array is then stuffed into an object that is then crammed into another array.

Comment: Taplar I am reading ...the link you shared to understand better

Comment: Zero00ne I did not notice I was having array for each user, I corrected by removing extra [ ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `find` the object of the userid in the array.

```js
var array1 = [];

var data =  { ['ABC123']: [{
     id: 1,
     name: 'john',
     email: 'john.doe@nomail.com'
      },
    ],
  };

array1.push(data);

let userId = 'ABC123';

let userObj = array1.find((x)=> x[userId] !== undefined);

if(userObj) {  // did the find return an object?
    let userData = userObj[userId][0];
    console.log(`name: ${userData.name}`);
    console.log(userData);
}
else {
    console.log(`user ${userId} not found.`);
}
```

By the way, it's not so common that a value would be used as a property name.
More often, such key is just a value of an objects property.

Which also makes the `find` or `filter` more straightforward.

For example:

```js
var array1 = [];

array1.push({
         userid : 'ABC123',
         id: 1,
         name: 'john',
         email: 'john.doe@nomail.com'
      });

let userId = 'ABC123';
let userData = array1.find((x)=> x.userid === userId);

if(userData) {  // did the find return an object?
    console.log(`name: ${userData.name}`);
    console.log(userData);
}
else {
    console.log(`user ${userId} not found.`);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to get only the name field inside the ABC123?

Comment: I get undefined for the name. console.log(userData.name);

Comment: The name is in an object that's in array.  See update.

Comment: I am not sure why I keep getting the Cannot read property 'name' of undefined with console.log('name: ', userData[0].name);

Comment: Did you notice that `[userId]` was used at the end of the find ?

Comment: That is what I was missing. Thanks.

Comment: ['ABC123']: [{ }] isn't it creating another array, I mean for each userId?

Comment: I can't answer that. I don't know the data nor  it's purpose. But I do find it suspicious that the user data objects are in an array.

Comment: I corrected by removing [ ] to ['ABC123']: { } and removing [0] from  console.log('name: ', userData.name);

the result is:
{
  buMqSZpEaKZABffDGNs5jzVK36Y2: 
    {
      id: '65',
      name: 'nameTest',
      email: 'myexmail@gmail.com'
    }
}

Comment: Ok. Good that you figured it out.  Well, personally I would prefere a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object for key/value pairs.

Comment: @UAJ Anyway, Map isn't fully supported yet by IE anyway.  But I added a sidenote to the answer.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. There is something I don't understand. For example,  if(array1.find((x)=> x[userId] !== undefined)[userId]){}else{}. if it finds the id it does work, but if it doesn't find  the id in the array it throws error Cannot read property 'xgyuFT145Tbgc' of undefined. Wasn't if supposed to execute 'else' and not throw error even if the 'else' is not there, pass. Even let userData = array1.find((x)=> x[userId] !== undefined)[userId]; if it does not find the id will give error. I wanted to check the userid, if the userid is in the array replace 'id' with a new id.

Comment: Well, that's true. Can't get a property from undefined. I've updated the answer with a check.

Comment: It checks, but does not return an object.....Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: Hmm, how about you log what's returned from the find.  And see what you're getting from it.  When I tested the current code it'll go to the `else` when the userId isn't in the array and nothing is found.  In my code I still used the `[0]` to get the first value of that array with the object that has id.  But if your object doesn't have such array that `[0]` ain't needed.

Comment: Now it does return an object. Thanks